# javax.ws.rs.client.Client l- JSON from a local file

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have simple REST client code like this, calling a service:

```
String myUrl = "http://somehost/someservice";      
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(JacksonFeature.class).build();
MyClass result = client.target(myUrl)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get(MyClass.class);
// work with result
```

All working fine. Now I want to exercise the processing code with some pre-canned test data I have stored in a JSON file. I hoped I could simply use a File URL

```
 String myUrl = "file://somepath/MyTest.json";
```

This fails with this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: class sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to class java.net.HttpURLConnection (sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection and java.net.HttpURLConnection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:632)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:654)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:648)
```

How can I tell the WS client to treat a file as a pseudo-service provider?

Comment: It's an HTTP client. So I'm not sure it's possible. Maybe with a custom Connector, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Samsothe says, Client is an HTTP client. For my purposes it's sufficient to use code like this instead

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

MyClass metData = mapper.readValue(
         Paths.get("sample.json").toFile(), 
         MyClass.class
    );
```

I can hide the choice between HTTP and File behind a Facade.